# Python script doesnt work?: Playing sound, measuring reaction time

Tags: python, loops, audio, measure, psychopy

I want to make a script, that measures how fast a participant is to press enter or space bar, only when they hear 2/30 sounds from sound files. 
So some times the user does not have to press anything, and the script still moves on to the next sound file. How do I do this? What I have right now is this: (instead of sound files, I have text atm.):

```
# Grounding of Words Experiment #

#Import libraries
import re
import glob
from psychopy import sound, visual, event, data, core, gui # imports a module for visual presentation and one for controlling events like key presses


# ID, age, gender box display
myDlg = gui.Dlg(title="Experiment") #, pos=(400,400)
myDlg.addField('ID:')
myDlg.addField('Age:')
myDlg.addField('Gender:', choices = ['Female', 'Male'])
myDlg.show()#you have to call show() for a Dlg
if myDlg.OK:
    ID = myDlg.data[0]
    Age = myDlg.data[1]
    Gender = myDlg.data[2]
else:
    core.quit()

trial=0

#Creates the outfile, that will be the file containing our data, the name of the file, as saved on the computer is the filename
out_file="Grounding_experiment_results.csv"
#Creates the header for the data
header="trial,ID,Gender,Age,Word,rt,SpaceKlik\n"
#opens the outfile in writemode
with open(out_file,"w") as f:
    f.write(header)#writes the header in the outfile


# define window
win = visual.Window(fullscr=True) # defines a window using default values (= gray screen, fullscr=False, etc)

# Instruction box display

def instruct(txt):
    instructions = visual.TextStim(win, text=txt, height = 0.05) # create an instruction text
    instructions.draw() # draw the text stimulus in a "hidden screen" so that it is ready to be presented 
    win.flip() # flip the screen to reveal the stimulus
    event.waitKeys() # wait for any key press

instruct('''
Welcome to the experiment!

You will be hearing different words.
Whenever you hear the word "Klik" and "Kast" please press the left mouse button.
Whenever you hear any other word - do nothing.
Try to be as fast and accurate as possible.
Please put on the headphones. 
The experiment will take 5 minutes. 

Press any key to start the experiment''')

# Play sound

# Function that makes up a trial

trial(word):
    global trial
    trial += 1
    if word in ["Klik", "Press", "Throw"]:
        condition = "press"
    else :
        condition = "no_press"
    event.clearEvents()
    for frame in range(90):
        text = visual.TextStim(win, text=word, height = 0.05)
        text.draw() # draw the text stimulus in a "hidden screen" so that it is ready to be presented 
        time_start=win.flip()
    try:
        key, time_key=event.getKeys(keyList=['space', 'escape'], timeStamped = True)[0] # wait for any key press
    except IndexError:
        key = "0"
        rt = "NA"
    else:
        if key=='escape': 
                core.quit()
        rt = time_key - time_start
    if key == "space" and condition=="press":
        accuracy = 1
    elif key == "0" and condition=="no_press":
        accuracy = 1
    else:
        accuracy = 0
    with open(out_file,"a") as f:
        f.write("{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}\n".format(trial,ID,Gender,Age,word,accuracy,rt,SpaceKlik))

# s = sound.Sound('sound.wav') 
# s.play()

# Register space bar press or mouse click

# Measure reaction time

# Check to see if answer is correct to sound - certain sound files are "klik". Others "kast", "løb", "sko" and so on

# Write csv logfile with coloumns: "ID", "Gender", "Word", "Correct/incorrect", "Reaction time", "Space/click"
```

I will all run in PsychoPy in the end. Thank you in advance for your kind assistance.

Comment: As a general tip, avoid having `trial` as a global variable. Simply increment it outside the `trial()` function and pass it as a second parameter to the function. Similarly, don't create a a text stimulus each time you run the instruction function (this is a time-expensive operation). Create it once, and pass the text stimulus to the function, along with the new text contents. This is a much larger problem in your trial function, where a text stimulus is re-instantiated on every frame. This is very time-inefficient and may cause timing problems.

Answer (score 0):

There are issues with your indenting so that not everything is being run within the trial function at the appropriate level. You can probably drop the exception handling to more directly check whether or not a response was made. Then make use of the `else:` clause to the `for` loop to handle what happens if the loop completes but no key was pressed. This avoids having to handle the logic of a non-response occurring on any given frame (which may not mean anything, if  the response will occur shortly afterwards).

Something like this general pseudocode:

```
# define window
win = visual.Window(fullscr=True)

# function to draw instructions (probably overkill unless run more than once)
def instruct(instructions = 'xxx'):
    # as you have above

# function to run each trial
def trial(number = -999, sound_name = 'A'):

    sound = Sound.sound(sound_name)

    if sound_name in ["Klik.wav", "Press.wav", "Throw.wav"]:
        condition = "press"
    else:
        condition = "no_press"

    event.clearEvents()

    sound.play()

    for frame in range(90):

        time_start = win.flip()

        keys = event.getKeys(keyList=['space', 'escape'], timeStamped = True)
        if keys: # if a non-empty list returned:
            key, time_key = keys[0]
            rt = time_key - time_start

            sound.stop() # ready to start next trial immediately

            if key == 'escape': 
                core.quit()

            if condition == "press":
                return {'accuracy':1, 'rt':rt}
            else:
                return {'accuracy':0, 'rt':rt}

    else: # the loop ended without a key press
        if condition == "press":
            return {'accuracy':0, 'rt':'NA'}
        else:
            return {'accuracy':1, 'rt':'NA'}

####
# run the experiment:
####

####
# show the instructions:
####
instruct('some instructions')

####
# run the trials:
####
for trial_num in range(10):

    # run each trial and get the results.
    # I'm not sure where you're getting your sound values
    # but they could be indexed from a list using the trial number:
    result = trial(number=trial_num, sound_name=sound_names[trial_num])

    # then save the values from the returned dictionary to a file
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright, nice - thank you! Now I have continued to try developing your script. I have added a trial list, and now I am not too sure what to do. My script looks like this:

```
# Grounding of Words Experiment #

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#Import libraries
import re
import glob
from psychopy import sound, visual, event, data, core, gui # imports a module for visual presentation and one for controlling events like key presses
import ppc

# ID, age, gender box display
myDlg = gui.Dlg(title="Experiment") #, pos=(400,400)
myDlg.addField('ID:')
myDlg.addField('Age:')
myDlg.addField('Gender:', choices = ['Female', 'Male'])
myDlg.show()#you have to call show() for a Dlg
if myDlg.OK:
    ID = myDlg.data[0]
    Age = myDlg.data[1]
    Gender = myDlg.data[2]
else:
    core.quit()

# define window
win = visual.Window(fullscr=True)


# function to draw instructions (probably overkill unless run more than once)
def instruct(txt):
    instructions = visual.TextStim(win, text=txt, height = 0.05) # create an instruction text
    instructions.draw() # draw the text stimulus in a "hidden screen" so that it is ready to be presented 
    win.flip() # flip the screen to reveal the stimulus
    event.waitKeys() # wait for any key press
    # as you have above


# function to run each trial
def trial(number = -999, sound_name = 'A'):

    sound = Sound.sound()

    if sound_name in ["dog-howling.wav"]:
        condition = "press"
    else:
        condition = "no_press"

    event.clearEvents()

    sound.play(sound_name)

    for frame in range(90):

        time_start = win.flip()

        keys = event.getKeys(keyList=['space', 'escape'], timeStamped = True)
        if keys: # if a non-empty list returned:
            key, time_key = keys[0]
            rt = time_key - time_start

            sound.stop() # ready to start next trial immediately

            if key == 'escape': 
                core.quit()

            if condition == "press":
                return {'accuracy':1, 'rt':rt}
            else:
                return {'accuracy':0, 'rt':rt}

    else: # the loop ended without a key press
        if condition == "press":
            return {'accuracy':0, 'rt':'NA'}
        else:
            return {'accuracy':1, 'rt':'NA'}
####
# define triallist

trial_list = []
conditions = ["klik", "notklik"]
sounds = ["dog-howling.wav", "sound2.wav", "sound3.wav"]
for condition in conditions:
    for sound in sounds:
        # Add a dictionary for every trial
            trial_list += [{
                'ID': ID,
                'age': AGE,
                'gender': GENDER,
                'condition': condition,
                'sounds': sound,
                'rating': '',
                'rt': ''
                    }]

# Randomize order
trial_list = sample(trial_list, len(trial_list))

# Add trial numbers
for i, trial in enumerate(trial_list):
    trial['no'] = i + 1 # start at 1

# write file

####
# run the experiment:
####

####
# show the instructions:
####
instruct('''Welcome to the experiment!

You will be hearing different words.
Whenever you hear the word "Klik" and "Kast" please press the left mouse button.
Whenever you hear any other word - do nothing.
Try to be as fast and accurate as possible.
Please put on the headphones. 
The experiment will take 5 minutes. 

Press any key to start the experiment''')

####
# run the trials:
####
for trial_num in range(10):

    # run each trial and get the results.
    # I'm not sure where you're getting your sound values
    # but they could be indexed from a list using the trial number:
    result = trial(number=trial_num, sound_name=sound_names[trial_num])

    # then save the values from the returned dictionary to a file+

#Creates the outfile, that will be the file containing our data, the name of the file, as saved on the computer is the filename
#out_file="Grounding_experiment_results.csv"
#Creates the header for the data
#header="trial,ID,Gender,Age,Word,rt,SpaceKlik\n"
#opens the outfile in writemode
#with open(out_file,"w") as f:
#    f.write(header)#writes the header in the outfile
```

Comment: You really need to look in to the `TrialHandler` class. Feed your trial list to that, and it will automatically handle keeping track of trial numbers, saving data and so on. There are a couple of examples under the Demos menu in PsychoPy's Coder view.